# Modificar elemento visual por outra thread

Tags: c#, winforms, thread, multithreading

Quero definir por um Thread o conteúdo numa RichTextBox mas recebo um erro dizendo

> Não é possível realizar chamadas de um outro thread distindo do mesmo TextBox

---

Ouvi falar que é possível utilizar a opção `Control.Invoke` ai fiquei muito na dúvida nesse ponto.

Resumindo, eu quero desenvolver um APP que sem iniciar o CMD com a janela, acompanhe comandos e possa enviar comandos ao CMD, já tenho o código pronto mas na hora que eu configuro `RedirectStandardOutput=true` acaba que apenas quando o processo fecha ele mostra o log.

Por isso eu gostaria de implementar um `Thread` em cima da textbox para com sem precisar o processo fechar e mostrar o "log".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como você não mostrou o código do que está tentando fazer, irei dar uma resposta mais genérica.

Você pode fazer isso

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => textBox.Text = "NovoTexto"));
```

Eu faria uma função para trocar o valor do `TextBox`, onde na própria função verificaria se é preciso usar o `Invoke` ou não. Isso é mais questão de gosto. Se te interessa, ficaria dessa forma.

```
public void SetText(TextBox txtbox, string texto) 
{
    if (txtbox.InvokeRequired)
        txtbox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => txtbox.Text = texto));
    else
        txtbox.Text = texto;        
}
```

Uso

```
SetText(textBox, "Novo Texto");
```