# Acessando objeto criado por outra thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Estou criando uma aplicação em C#. Os elementos da interface gráfica são criados pela *main-thread*, e pus uma segunda *thread* para executar um processo que é muito longo.

O problema é que estou tentando acessar um elemento da interface gráfica com essa segunda *thread* e estou recebendo uma exceção do tipo "operação inválida".

O objeto da interface que estou tentando acessar é uma barra de progresso:

```
ProgressBar.IsInderterminate = true; // linha da exceção
```

Como posso acessar esse objeto por meio da minha segunda *thread*?

Comment: Não tem como responder isto olhando para uma linha do código. Inclusive essa propriedade não documenta esta exceção, então o problema ocorre em outro lugar, mesmo que acabe aparecendo aí. Sem código, sem informações detalhes não tem como ajudar.

Comment: Na verdade, tem sim @bigown Ele está tentando acessar um controle criado na _thread_ principal por outra _thread_ e isso não é possível (não naturalmente).

Comment: Porém a pergunta é duplicada desta outra ([Modificar elemento visual por outra thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93029/18246))

Comment: @jbueno eu acho até possível inferir sobre o que é, mas pode não ser o que parece porque não tem quase nada descrevendo o problema. Sequer sabemos se usa STA, mesmo sendo provável.

Comment: Consegui. Obrigado. Não tem como detalhar mais. Essa exceção é a única mensagem do depurador. Eu tenho que fazer a declaração de uma forma especial. Questões de STA lançam outro tipo de exceção.

Comment: @jbueno , a duplicação da pergunta é quase inevitável para um iniciante, pois a pergunta do link indicado está de maneira que não consigo identificar que se trata do mesmo problema, embora a resposta sirva.

Comment: @Paulo Eu sei. Isso sem contar que o sistema de buscas do site é horrível. Duplicatas não são uma má ideia, só é importante mantê-las vinculadas.