# Chamar método de outra classe em uma Task c#

Tags: c#, wpf, thread, multithreading, async

Estou tentando fazer uma chamada em Task de um método de outra Classe:

```
Diretorios diretorios = new Diretorios();
await Task.Run(() => diretorios.CopiaDiretorios(tbxVersaoAtual.Text, tbxServerCopia.Text));
```

Só que recebo a seguinte Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'O thread de chamada não pode acessar este objeto porque ele pertence a um thread diferente.'

Realmente não é possível fazer isto que estou tentando?

Eu preciso realmente esperar a execução desse método antes de prosseguir a execução e não posso bloquear a UI Thread logo preciso rodar em uma Task.

PS: O método de chamada é async e o método chamado está retornando uma Task como deve ser.

Alguma solução?

Comment: É Windows Forms?

Comment: Não, eu estou utilizando WPF.

Answer (score 1):

A resposta é basicamente a mesma desta pergunta aqui: [Modificar elemento visual por outra thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93029/18246)

A diferença é que, no WPF, cada controle tem uma propriedade chamada `Dispatcher` que contém os elementos necessários para fazer o `Invoke`.

Exemplo funcional:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        SetText(textBox, "Qualquer texto");
    });
}

public static void SetText(TextBox txtbox, string texto)
{
    if (txtbox.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        txtbox.Text = texto;            
    else
        txtbox.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => txtbox.Text = texto, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
}
```

Comment: No caso, o Dispatcher serve para alterar propriedades de objetos dentro de threads diferentes das quais eles foram criadas certo?
No meu caso eu preciso chamar um método de outra classe como um Task.
repare que estou instanciando uma nova classe e tentando chamar o método dela em uma Task. Como poderia utilizar Dispatcher.Invoke nesse caso?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVIDO!

Na verdade eu tinha que alterar o retorno do método que eu estava chamado de Void para Task.

Após fazer isso funcionou.

Anyway, muito obrigado